# C++ Input Stream fail

Tags: c++, vector, input

I've wrote a program which is basically asking the user to input the elements for two vector ints. Then it compares this vectors, but the program ignores my second input stream. However, the console does not print an error it skips just the second input.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
//Introduction
cout << "This is a comparison program between two vectors of ints." << endl;

vector<int> ivec1;
vector<int> ivec2;
//First vector
int v1;
cout << "Insert the values for the first vector." << endl; 
while (cin >> v1) {
    ivec1.push_back(v1);
}
cin.clear();
//Second vector
int v2;
cout << "Insert the values for the second vector." << endl;
while (cin >> v2) {
    ivec2.push_back(v2);
}
cin.clear();
//Equal? If yes, first smaller?
if (ivec1 == ivec2) {
    cout << "Both vectors are equal." << endl;
}
else {
    if (ivec1 < ivec2)
        cout << "This two vectors are unequal and the first vector is smaller." << endl;
    else
        cout << "This two vectors are unequal and the second vector is smaller." << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you ready to learn how to step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: You keep using `cin.clear()`. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm afraid OP doesn't have the slightest clue. But that's going to be common in questions more and more. I don't bother even asking anymore most of the time. Just DVCV :-P ..

Comment: @DrewDormann Iam new to c++. I don't know how to use one.

Comment: @JanGross Using the debugger is one of the most essential skills to master a programming language! Most of the IDEs (you're probably using one) just provide the feature to step through your code out of the box.

Comment: @JanGross welcome to StackOverflow and welcome to C++!  Now that you've progressed enough that you're writing bugs *(just like us pros)* the next step is to walk through your code with a debugger.  Then when you're *really* stuck, you can describe the research effort you've made.

Answer (score 0):

From "console does not print an error" (assuming doesn't print anything), and "skips the second input stream", I wonder if you're terminating the program instead of providing the correct EOF stream (by hitting Ctrl + D) to move on to the second input stream.

Comment: I provide EOF. The first stream is ok but then it skips the second input stream and provides the second vector 0 elements. Then the comparision says that the first vector is bigger.